# Id en Html variable

Tags: javascript, css, html5, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

estoy teniendo un problema con un label, le quiero cambiar el id (que vaya variando el numero de acuerdo a la mesa que pertenece) y en la linea:

```
document.getElementById('labelUsuario').id = "" + numeroMesa + "";
```

me da el siguiente error:

```
angular.js:13920 TypeError: Cannot set property 'id' of null
at ChildScope.$scope.MostrarMesasPorZona (appPedidosMozo.js:42)
at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:14817), <anonymous>:4:332)
at expensiveCheckFn (angular.js:15906)
at callback (angular.js:25885)
at ChildScope.$eval (angular.js:17682)
at ChildScope.$apply (angular.js:17782)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:25890)
at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3)
at HTMLButtonElement.v.handle (jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3)
(anonymous) @ angular.js:13920
```

aquí dejo mi código:

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app="myAppPedidoMozo" ng-controller="myCtrlPedidoMozo" style="background-image:url('imagen/Fondo madera.jpg');">
<div class="row" id="divZonas">
    <div class="tab" ng-repeat="a in zonas">
        <button class="tablinks" id="BtnZona" ng-click="MostrarMesasPorZona(a)">{{a.nombreZona}}</button>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <form class="form-horizontal">


        <div id="ZonaSeleccionada" class="tabcontent">
            <div class="form-group">

                <div class="col-xs-12" id="MesasDiv">
                    <div ng-repeat="a in mesas" class="col-xs-1" style="margin:5%;">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-circle btn-lg" id="{{a.numeroMesa}}">

                            {{a.numeroMesa}}
                        </button>
                        <label id="labelUsuario" style="visibility:hidden;"><i class="fa fa-user-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
```

**ANGULARJS**

```
angular.module("myAppPedidoMozo", []).controller("myCtrlPedidoMozo", function ($scope, $http) {

$http.get('/api/Pedidos/GetPedido/').then(function (response) {
    $scope.pedidos = response.data;
});

$scope.MostrarMesasPorZona = function (Zona) {
    debugger;
    $http.get('/api/Mesas/GetMesasPorZona/' + Zona.idZona).then(function (response) {
        $scope.mesas = response.data;
    });

    document.getElementById('ZonaSeleccionada').style.display = "block";
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.pedidos.length; i++) {
        var numeroMesa = $scope.pedidos[i].numeroMesa;

        if (numeroMesa === null) {

        } else {

            document.getElementById('labelUsuario').id = "" + numeroMesa + "";
            document.getElementById($scope.pedidos[i].numeroMesa).style.visibility = "hidden";
            if ($scope.pedidos[i].idUsuario === null) {
                document.getElementById($scope.pedidos[i].numeroMesa).style.color = "red"; }}}}});
```

una alternativa a esto fue en la linea del html en el label cambiarla por

```
<label id="{{a.numeroMesa}}" style="visibility:hidden;"><i class="fa fa-user-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
```

y así tendría un id que varia de acuerdo a la mesa en cuestión, pero el error según el debugger entraba en ExpensiveCheckOld en False. (no tengo idea porque)
si no entendí mal es porque no recupera el numero de mesa({{a.numeroMesa}}) por eso queda en null,(algo de angular) y de allí no puedo cambiar las propiedades. 
Ojala me puedan decir otra alternativa o solucionar este problema.

A su vez no se si es que el método http.Get a la api de mesas la esta haciendo en el mismo momento que intenta recuperar el id(en el div del html que se genera por la lista de mesas ) y al no hacer todavía la lista de mesas no tiene el elemento label(no se si me explico.) Como solucionar esto porque a la lista de las mesas la hago luego de la carga de pagina, ya que necesito hacerlo por filtro de zonas(a la lista de mesas la cargo luego de hacer click en algún boton de una zona en cuestión)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando haces el primer clic al label funciona porque todavia tiene el id  `labelUsuario` y procedes a cambiarle el id por lo que al hacer el segundo cli y buscar el elemento  `document.getElementById('labelUsuario')`, no lo encontrara porque le cambiaste el id en la ejecucion anterior.

Por ejemplo, aqui siempre que se hace clic sobre el boton se cambia el id. Solo funciona en la primera porque efectivamente su id es prueba pero despues cambia a 0 y no puede ser encontrado:

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl", function($scope){
 
 var id = 0;
 $scope.cambiar = function(){
   var label = document.querySelectorAll("label")[0];
   console.log("el id del label es:" + label.id);
   document.getElementById("prueba").id = (id++).toString();
   console.log("se cambio el id dinamicamente");
 }
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
   <label id="prueba">Preuba label</label>
   <button ng-click="cambiar()">cambiar</button>
</div>
```

En resumen, estas buscando un elemento con el id "labelUsuario" pero cambias ese id por lo que lanza null. Una sugerencia es guardar el numero de la mesa en un atributo `data` del elemento para luego leerlo:

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl", function($scope){
 
 var id = 0;
 $scope.cambiar = function(){
   
   var $prueba = $("#prueba");
   $prueba.data("id", (id++).toString());
   console.log("el data-id actual es " + $prueba.data("id"));

   
 }
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
   <label id="prueba">Preuba label</label>
   <button ng-click="cambiar()">cambiar</button>
</div>
```

---

En cuanto a la peticion al api de los pedidos, lo mas aconsejable seria deshabilitar el boton que ejecuta el metodo MostrarMesasPorZona hasta que carguen los pedidos porque ajax es asincrono por lo que puede que todavia no haya cargado los permisos cuando se ejecute el metodo. Asi una vez tengas los pedidos, habilitas el boton y estas completamente segura que puedes continuar.

Comment: Tal cual, muchas gracias por tu ayuda... 
Mi gran problema es como poder manipular el orden en que se dan las cosas. Se carga el html- se carga el javascript - va hasta la api - vuelve a javascript y se carga el html (por eso es que como se me cargaba el html al ultimo el id={{a.numeroMesa}} no me funcionaba, creo que este es el orden). Vos podrías aconsejarme alguna pagina o algo que hable de este tema?

Comment: Me dijeron que para manipular ciertos mensajes puedo usar promises... y que dependen del callback..puede ser?